# Multiple Random Includes from Directory with Sub-Directories

Tags: php

I have a directory containing sub directories which each contain a series of files. I'm looking for a script that will look inside the sub directories *and* randomly return a specified number of files.

There are a few scripts that can search a single directories (not sub folders), and other scripts that can search sub folders but only return one file.

To put a little context on the situation, the returned files will be included as li's in an rotating banner.

Thanks in advance for any help, hopefully this is possible.

I think I've got there, not *exactly* what I set out to achieve but works good enough, arguably better for the purpose, I'm using the following function:

```
<?php function RandomFile($folder='', $extensions='.*'){
   // fix path:
    $folder = trim($folder);
    $folder = ($folder == '') ? './' : $folder;

    // check folder:
    if (!is_dir($folder)){ die('invalid folder given!'); }

    // create files array
    $files = array();

    // open directory
    if ($dir = @opendir($folder)){

        // go trough all files:
        while($file = readdir($dir)){

            if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
                preg_match('/\.('.$extensions.')$/', $file)){

                // feed the array:
                $files[] = $file;                
            }            
        }        
        // close directory
        closedir($dir);    
    }
    else {
        die('Could not open the folder "'.$folder.'"');
    }

    if (count($files) == 0){
        die('No files where found :-(');
    }

    // seed random function:
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

    // get an random index:
    $rand = mt_rand(0, count($files)-1);

    // check again:
    if (!isset($files[$rand])){
        die('Array index was not found! very strange!');
    }

    // return the random file:
    return $folder . "/" . $files[$rand];

}


$random1 = RandomFile('project-banners/website-design');
while (!$random2 || $random2 == $random1) {
    $random2 = RandomFile('project-banners/logo-design');
}
while (!$random3 || $random3 == $random1 || $random3 == $random2) {
    $random3 = RandomFile('project-banners/design-for-print');
}
?>
```

And echoing the results into the container (in this case the ul):

```
<?php include($random1) ;?>
<?php include($random2) ;?>
<?php include($random3) ;?>
```

Thanks to quickshiftin for his help, however it was a little above my skill level.

For info the original script which I changed an be found at:

http://randaclay.com/tips-tools/multiple-random-image-php-script/

Answer (score 0):

Scrubbing the filesystem every single time to randomly select a file to display will be really slow.  You should index the directory structure ahead of time.  You can do this many ways, try a simple [find command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) or if you really want to use PHP my favorite choice would be [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) plus [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).

Put all the results into one file and just read from there when you select a file to display.  You can use the line numbers as an index, and the [rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function to pick a line and thus a file to display.  You might want to consider something more evenly distributed than rand though, you know to keep the advertisers happy :)

EDIT:

Adding a simple real-world example:

```
// define the location of the portfolio directory
define('PORTFOLIO_ROOT', '/Users/quickshiftin/junk-php');
// and a place where we'll store the index
define('FILE_INDEX', '/tmp/porfolio-map.txt');

// if the index doesn't exist, build it
// (this doesn't take into account changes to the portfolio files)
if(!file_exists(FILE_INDEX))
    shell_exec('find ' . PORTFOLIO_ROOT . ' > ' . FILE_INDEX);

// read the index into memory (very slow but easy way to do this)
$aIndex = file(FILE_INDEX);

// randomly select an index
$iIndex = rand(0, count($aIndex) - 1);

// spit out the filename
var_dump(trim($aIndex[$iIndex]));
```

Comment: Thanks Quickshiftin, sorry I should have mentioned I have next to no PHP skills. Are there any working examples you could point me towards? P.S. - The random files are links to design projects in my portfolio, not advertisers :-)